# if User.objects.get(email=self.validated_data['email']).exist():

Tags: python, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

**User matching query does not exist.**

I receive this error and I can not understand why this happens?

```
from rest_framework import serializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
password2= serializers.CharField(style={'input_type'},write_only=True)
class Meta:
    model= User
    fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'password2']
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only':True}}
    
def save(self):
    password=self.validated_data['password']
    password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
    if password != password2:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'error': 'password and password2 do not match'})
    if User.objects.get(email=self.validated_data['email']).exist():
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'error':'email already exists'})
    
    account=User(email=self.validated_data['email'], username=self.validated_data['username'])
    account.set_password(password)
    account.save()

    return account
```

Comment: `get()` is get an instance, not querset. Using: `.filter()`. So: `User.objects.filter(email=self.validated_data['email']).exist()`

Comment: thank you for your response , now I get this error "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'exist'"

Comment: `exists()` please. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

As Mahrus explained in the comment, `.get` will return instance (one) if it exists, and raise `ObjectDoesNotExist` if it doesn't.
If multiple objects are matching given query, `.get` will raise `MultipleObjectReturned`. It is usually used when you want to get object by id.

In other cases, use `.filter` which will always return value, but it is a queryset, not an object instance. So for example, if you use id to `filter`, one object will match the query but you still has to call `.first()` to get it.

- `Object.get(id='ID')` - returns object instance (or raises exception)
- `Object.filter(id='ID')` - returns a `queryset` instance
- `Object.filter(id='ID').first()` - returns an object instance

Check out the [queryset documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/)